# Overriding inline CSS in next js sass module

Tags: html, css, next.js, css-modules

I use the `Twemoji` library to get emoji icons in my Next js App, they appear as `<span><img></span>` in the final HTML and I can override their default width and height using `!important` in my globals.scss file:

```
.customize { //Parent class containers 3 buttons, each one has an emoji element
    top: 88%;
    right: calc(50vw - (52.2px + 3rem));
    button {
      span img[style]{
        width: 35px !important;
        height: 35px !important;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I tried to extract it as a `[].module.scss` file, everything works but the images don't change size whatsoever. Why?

**Edit**
Here is the component I'm trying to style:

```
import ThemeButton from '../components/themeCustomizeButton' // a button that renders an emoji
import LanguageSwitcher from '../components/LanguageSwitch' // a button that renders an emoji
import Complex from '../components/ComplexitySwitch' // a button that renders an emoji
import styles from "../styles/local/components/customize.module.scss" // importing .module.scss

function Customizing() {
    return(
        <section className={styles.customize}>
            <ThemeButton />
            <LanguageSwitcher />
            <Complex />
        </section>
    )
}

export default Customizing
```

Comment: How are you applying the styles from the Sass module? Can you share the code you have in that component?

Comment: @juliomalves I added the component to the question

Answer (score -1):

Just use this code before wherever you are trying to extract

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  // Set the size of the rendered Emojis
  // This can be set to 16x16, 36x36, or 72x72
  twemoji.size = '36x36';

});
```

Comment: I don't want to use jquery within my Next.js app. and the emoji size changes dynamically based on the window width.